# Executing a variable array of functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I want to create a thread which runs a list of functions which are passed to it, the list can be updated real time so a function in the list could be switched out.

What is the correct way to do this? How would I create a variable list of functions in Python?

Comment: What have you tried? You can pass functions objects to other functions in python.  From there, you just need to handle the variability, which could be done by passing an iterable of functions, or by utilizing *args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can be stored in lists just like variables and data structures can be. When adding them to a list, be sure to only use the name of the function and to exclude the `()` so that it adds the function itself, rather than the output of the function.

There are a couple ways you could make it so that the list can be updated in real time. As long as the thread is able to look up externally accessible data, it will work. For two examples, the thread could access class data or data stored in a file.

Here's some sample code for a class data example:

```
import threading
import time


class Obj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = []

    def call_functions(self):
        for function in self.functions:
            function()
            time.sleep(5)

    def add_function(self, function):
        self.functions.append(function)

def a():
    print("a")

def b():
    print("b")

def c():
    print("c")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Obj()
    obj.add_function(a)
    obj.add_function(b)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=obj.call_functions)
    thread.start()
    obj.add_function(c)
```

Comment: thanks! One other question, how can I dynamically pass arguments? Basically I want the list of functions and a list which contains the arguments, the problem is the arguments are variable length and function dependent so it's not clear how I would pass the arguments to the function.

Comment: You could store the arguments in a separate list, each within their own tuple. That way, `obj.arguments[x]` corresponds to `obj.functions[x]`, no matter how many arguments each function takes. You can then use the `*` operator to unpack them. For example: given tuple `arguments` that contains all arguments for function `function`, `function(*arguments)` passes those arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Here is example:

**Code**

```
class a:
    def f1(self, i):
        print(f'function 1 executed, index={i}')

def f2(i):
    print(f'function 2 executed, index={i}')

def f3(i):
    print(f'function 3 executed, index={i}')

object_of_a = a()

function_list = [object_of_a.f1, f2]

for arg, fn in enumerate(function_list):
    fn(arg)

function_list[1] = f3

for arg, fn in enumerate(function_list):
    fn(arg)
```

**Output**

```
function 1 executed, index=0
function 2 executed, index=1

function 1 executed, index=0
function 3 executed, index=1
```

Here is an example with a list of arguments:

**Code**

```
def f1(i):
    print(f'function 1 executed, arg={i}')

def f2(i):
    print(f'function 2 executed, arg={i}')

def f3(i):
    print(f'function 3 executed, arg={i}')

function_list = [f1, f2]
argument_list = ['arg1', 'arg2']

for arg, fn in zip(argument_list, function_list):
    fn(arg)

function_list[1] = f3

for arg, fn in zip(argument_list, function_list):
    fn(arg)
```

**Output**

```
function 1 executed, arg=arg1
function 2 executed, arg=arg2

function 1 executed, arg=arg1
function 3 executed, arg=arg2
```

Comment: interesting, I did not know you could to this, how does this work if the function is a method in an object?

Comment: Also how might I pass arguments along with them?

Comment: If the function is a method of another class, you can still reference the function as an object (cls.foo for the function foo() in class cls).  If you need to pass arguments, you do that when you call the function: `x = cls.foo` and then `x(args)`

Comment: @FourierFlux I've updated it with code that passes arguments

Comment: Thanks, I want to give both of you answers!

Comment: @FourierFlux, hey I've also added code where function is a method in an object like you had asked.